# Is non-tangential force produce angular acceleration

Tags: rotational-dynamics, acceleration

As torque is the only reason for angular acceleration but... When radial force act on a body it automatically become zero as it passes through center
And only thing left is tangential force which is responsible for the angular acceleration as torque is there. I want to know is any non tangential force on a rigid body can cause angular velocity to change to have angular acceleration

Answer (score 0):

A non-tangential force which has a tangential component will cause a change in angular velocity.  Also an inward radial force which is larger than that required to maintain centripetal acceleration will reduce the radius, and conservation of angular momentum will cause an increase in angular velocity.

Comment: That you want to tell us that, non tangential force too produce angular acceleration

Comment: I listed the conditions that make that true.